# Run before hook for every browser

Tags: testing, browser, automation, hook, testcafe

In TestCafé, I want to run a test in different browsers in parallel. Each session should sign up and log in with a different user account.

I tried to achieve this with the `before` hook:

```
let user = null;

fixture("My fixture")
  .page("http://localhost:8080")
  .before(() => {
    user = faker.internet.email();
  });

test("login", async t => {
  // using user in here
});
```

However, this hook is just executed once for **all** browsers, I need to run it for **each** browser so that I can have different credentials each time.

Is this feasible?

**This is the NPM script:**

`testcafe firefox,chrome,edge tests.js`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `beforeEach` hook for this.
https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/test-code-structure.html#test-hooks

Comment: Thanks, this indeed runs for every browser, but the `beforeEach` hook runs before each test. I have more than 1 test in my fixture and would like to share the `user` data across them. It seems that the `before` hook works exactly for that purpose, but then I have the browser issue... Any idea?

Comment: I re-structured my tests and now this solution is working for me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I reconsidered this solution and think that you could use the TestCafe [User Roles](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/user-roles.html) feature in your scenario. You can create separate roles for different browsers and then choose one of them in the `beforeEach` hook based on the `userAgent` string. Here is an [example](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/examples-of-using-client-functions.html#obtain-a-browser-alias-within-a-test) how to obtain the `userAgent` using a client function.